# gradlew assembleRelease failed

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, apk

I want to try my app without the debug features. So I need to create APK file.
I applied the `gradlew assembleRelease` code to do that. However, because  I use react-native-video, I have mp4 file in my images. It gives me error while compiling:

> :app:mergeReleaseResources
>   C:\Users\USERNAME\MYApp\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\img_loadingscreen.mp4:
>   Error: The file name must end with .xml or .png
>   :app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
>
>   > C:\Users\USERNAME\MYApp\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-mdpi\img_loadingscreen.mp4:
>   >     Error: The file name must end with .xml or .png
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Help me to fix this issue.

Comment: I haven't used React Native personally, but mp4 files can't be referenced from drawable folders. Try res/raw, and double-check in the documentation for react-native-video to see where they expect you to store such files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a particular reason you're storing the mp4 in the drawable directory? If it's for different size screens, can't you just adjust the mp4 to fit the screen through react-native and just store the mp4 elsewhere?

Comment: Umm, I didn't put the video in drawable directory on purpose. It was sitting in img folder, however, when I try to build, the compiler gives me this error. So, where should I put that file?

Comment: Ok, you can store it anywhere. I keep a res folder within src in my react-native project. You should be able to just do that, and when you display the splash screen just have it play the video from there.

'./res/video/img_loadingscreen.mp4'